# Error Message: Uncaught Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, styled-components

I get a blankpage when I try to run my app and nothing is being rendered.

> Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
>
> 1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
> 2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
> 3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
>    See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.

```
import React,{ useState} from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components'
import MenuIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Menu';
import CloseIcon  from '@material-ui/icons/Close';

function Header() {
    const [burgerState,setBurgerState] = useState(false);
    return (
    <Container>
        <a href='#'>
            <img src='/images/logo.svg' alt=''/>
        </a>
        <MenuGroup>
            <div>Model S</div>
            <div>Model X</div>
            <div>Model Y</div>
        </MenuGroup>
        <RightMenu>
            <a href='#'>Shop</a>
            <a href='#'>Tesla Account</a>
        <MenuIconContainer onClick={ () => setBurgerState(true)} >
            <MenuIcon/>
        </MenuIconContainer>
        </RightMenu>
        <BurgerNav status={burgerState}>
            <CloseContainer>
              <Close onClick={ () => setBurgerState(false)} />
            </CloseContainer>
            <li><a href='#'>Model S</a></li>
            <li><a href='#'>Model Y</a></li>
            <li><a href='#'>Existing inventory</a></li>
            <li><a href='#'>Used inventory</a></li>
            <li><a href='#'>Trade-in</a></li>
            <li><a href='#'>Cybertruck</a></li>
            <li><a href='#'>Roadster</a></li>
            <li><a href='#'>Semi</a></li>
            <li><a href='#'>Charging</a></li>
        </BurgerNav >
    </Container>
  )
}

export default Header;

const Container = styled.div`
display: flex;
min-height: 60px;
align-items: center;
justify-content: space-between;
padding: 0 20px;
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
z-index: 10;
`;


const MenuGroup = styled.div`
display: flex;
text-transform: uppercase;
div {
    font-weight: 600;
    padding: 0 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

@media(max-width: 760px) {
    display: none;
}
`;

const RightMenu = styled.div`
display: flex;
a {
    font-weight: 600;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding-right: 20px;
}
`;

const MenuIconContainer = styled.div`
display:flex;
align-iems:center;
cursor:pointer;
`;

const CloseContainer = styled.div`
display: flex;
justify-content: flex-end;
`

const Close = styled(CloseIcon)`
`;

const BurgerNav = styled.div`
position: fixed;
width: 300px;
background: white;
top: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
padding: 20px;
list-style: none;
transform: ${props => props.status ? 'translateX(0)' : 'translateX(100%)'};
transition: transform 0.2s ease-in;
li {
    padding: 15px 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
    a {
        font-weight: 600;
    }
}
`
```

Answer (score 0):

Your component doesn't have an invalid hook call. Your code is ok, (apart from unrelated undefined "Close" on line 27. Did you mean "CloseIcon" from MUI? And an unrelated typo "align-iems in MenuIconContainer.

Check the other components because the code you paste here is ok. Where are you calling the invalid Hook.
For this error, there are only 3 reasons you might be seeing it:

1. using a version of react-dom that doesn't support Hooks
2. breaking the hook rules (like calling it outside functional components, in a class component for example,or not calling it at the top level of the body)
3. having more than one copy of React